# How to reset drop-down in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using angular reactive forms I have a drop down in my form and I'm using reset method to reset my form , when I'm using the reset option I don't see drop-down is resetting

**testing.ts file:**

```
myMethod() {
  this.myForm.reset();
}
```

**testing.html:**

```
<div>
  <select formControlName="abc" (ngModelChange)="myMethod($event)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> {{item.name}}/>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" value="reset" (click)=myMethod() />
```

when I tried this and click on button I see drop down is showing empty value instead of "Select".

Comment: Stackblitz minimal repro would be good to help you out

Comment: Html 5 has a new input coupled with a new datalist tag.  Super easy and bindable.

Answer (score 2):

Try with resetForm() as :

```
public resetForm() {
 this.myForm.reset({
  abc: 0
 });
}
```

Change the default value for first select as :

```
 <option value="0">Select</option>
```

Comment: thanks this worked and if i want to disable can do it here ? if yes can you please suggest..

Comment: Maybe you want: <option value="0" disabled>Select</option>